# RxJava2, Android, Webview Create Observable in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

Just getting started with trying to "Rx-ify" some of Android's Webview events.

```
class PageStartData(val url: String, val favicon: Bitmap?)

myWebview.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {

   val pageStartEvents: Observable<PageStartData> = Observable.create{ emitter->
      override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap){
          emitter.onNext(PageStartData(url, favicon))
      }
   }

}
```

And I have found that the onPageStarted function is out of scope in the emitter lambda function. Very simple, I'm sure. How to fix?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:

```
sealed class WebViewEvent {
    data class PageStartData(val url: String?,
                             val favicon: Bitmap?) : WebViewEvent()
}
```

...

```
class RxWebViewWrapper(private val webView: WebView) : ObservableOnSubscribe<WebViewEvent> {
    override fun subscribe(emitter: ObservableEmitter<WebViewEvent>) {
        webView.webViewClient = object :WebViewClient(){
            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?,
                                       url: String?,
                                       favicon: Bitmap?) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                emitter.onNext(WebViewEvent.PageStartData(url, favicon))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
val source = Observable.create<WebViewEvent>(RxWebViewWrapper(myWebview))
```

Comment: OK - so that makes the WebClient scope internal to the Observable rather than the other way around. How would you filter the events so you only get the ones you care about?

Comment: You can do this by using rx `filter` operator `source.filter { it is WebViewEvent.PageStartData }...` or with kotlin's `when-is` construction `source.subscribe { when (it) { is WebViewEvent.PageStartData -> { ... }}`

Comment: Thanks very much. That's going to help massively to get me started. Another tricky issue I can see coming is doing this with ShouldInterceptRequest, which requires a return value. Don't suppose you've done that as well?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html)

```
myWebview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        private val pageStartSubject = PublishSubject.create<PageStartData>()
        val pageStartEvents: Observable<PageStartData> = pageStartSubject

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap) {
            pageStartSubject.onNext(PageStartData(url, favicon))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm trying to avoid using subjects for the time being. You're right, though, this would work.